# Python: Try/Except around whole module

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a python module containing functions and a few classes.  This module is basically used as a tool-set by several of my co-workers.

I want to set-up a sort of bug reporting system where anytime someone generates an exception that I don't handle, an email will be sent with information on the exception.  This way I can continually improve the robustness of my code and the help-fullness of my own error messages.  Is the best way to do this to just put a try/except block around the entire module?

Comment: You might want to look at the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module.  That way you could log exceptions to a file and later send emails using the contents of log files.

Comment: you wil receive emails only if there were exceptions during the module *loading*. which does not seem like what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons I think your approach might not be the best.

Sometimes exceptions *should* be thrown.  For example, if I pass some stupid argument to a function, it should complain by throwing an exception. You don't want to get an email every time someone passes a string instead of an integer, etc. do you?

Besides, wrapping the entire thing in a try...except won't work, as that will only be catching exceptions that would occur during the definition of the classes/functions (when your module is loaded/imported).  For example,

```
# Your python library
try:
   def foo():
       raise Exception('foo exception')
       return 42
except Exception as e:
   print 'Handled: ', e

# A consumer of your library
foo()
```

The exception is still uncaught.

Comment: If he’s maintaining his code, those stupid little cases would eventually have checks (preventing exceptions) and there should be fewer emails over time. You could probably turn off emails while in active development environment and turn it on for production.

Comment: @vol7ron How should `int()` be improved to not throw an exception when you pass it `'zzz'`?

Comment: If it’s an issue, I imagine you have a number of options: (1) add value/type checking, (2) force default values, (3) cast value or fix the error. Basically, do whatever needs to be done to avoid the exception bubbling up to the mailer. In your case, a check would be added on the argument before passing it in as a value to `int()`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can make your own `SelfMailingException` and subclass it. Not that I would recommend this approach.

another option:

```
def raises(*exception_list):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*x, **y):
            try:
                f(*x, **y)
            except Exception as e:
                if not isinstance(e, tuple(exception_list)):
                    print('send mail')
                    # send mail
                raise
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

usage:

```
@raises(MyException)
def foo(): 
    ...
```